# comparing the contents of 2 lines of a file and adding them using perl

Tags: perl, scripting

I have a file called `listofvalues.txt`. The file has over 1000 lines and 5 columns.

```
1,232,3434,54343,434343  
1,232,100,4546,3456  
1,122,45454,4546,3456  
2,212,334,5555,4654  
...  
...
```

I want to add up the values of the third column if column 1 and 2 are equal and print the result into a file like as follows

```
1,232,3534,54343,434343  
1,122,45454,4546,3456  
2,212,334,5555,4654  
....  
.........  
.........  
......
```

how do you think I can do it in Perl? Since I am new to Perl I am finding it hard to do.

Comment: Is the file sorted? / are all of the rows that you want to merge in this manner next to each other.  And do you really want to throw away the information in the the 4th and 5th columns of the second entry?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3):

This program works by maintaining an array `@data` containing a list of all records with unique `column1|column2` keys. The first time a new key is encountered in the file the complete record is pushed onto the stack. Each subsequent encounter just adds the third field of the record to the original value.

The hash `%data` maintains references to the element of `@data` corresponding to each different value of the key.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'listofvalues.txt' or die $!;

my @data;
my %data;

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my @record = split /,/;
  my $key = join '|', @record[0,1];
  if ($data{$key}) {
    $data{$key}[2] += $record[2];
  }
  else {
    push @data, ($data{$key} = \@record);
  }
}

print join(',', @$_), "\n" for @data;
```

**output**

```
1,232,3534,54343,434343  
1,122,45454,4546,3456  
2,212,334,5555,4654
```

---

**Update**

A one-line solution

```
perl -F, -ane '$k="@F[0,1]";$s{$k}?$s{$k}[2]+=$F[2]:do{push@d,$k;$s{$k}=[@F]};END{$\"=',';print"@{$s{$_}}"for@d}' listofvalues.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one-linerish:

```bash
  perl -F, -lane '
```

```perl
  BEGIN { $, = "," }

  if(defined(@A)) {
    if($A[0] == $F[0] and $A[1] == $F[1]) {
      $A[3] +=  $F[3];
    } else {
      print @A;
      @A = (@F);
    }
  } else {
    @A = (@F);
  }

  END { print @A }' listofvalues.txt
```

See `perlrun(1)` for the implications of switches.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you *can* do it in a one-liner doesn't mean you should ;)

```
$ perl -F',' -lane '
push @order, [ @F[0,1] ]
  unless $seen{$F[0]}{$F[1]}++; # Preserve order
$total{$F[0]}{$F[1]} += $F[2];  # Sum up
$value{$F[0]}{$F[1]} = join ',' => @F[0,1], $total{$F[0]}{$F[1]}, @F[3..$#F];
} END {
    print $value{$_->{0]}{$_->[1]} for @order;
' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the database approach, although it doesn't deal with col4 or col5.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:CSV:");
$dbh->{'csv_tables'}->{'data'} = { 'file' => 'o33.txt',
    'col_names' => [qw/col1 col2 col3 col4 col5/]};

my $sql = <<SQL;
select col1, col2, SUM(col3)
from data
group by col1, col2
order by col1, col2
SQL

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$sth->execute;

{
    local $" = ',';
    while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref ) {
        print "@$row\n";
    }
}

__END__
C:\Old_Data\perlp>type o33.txt
1,232,3434,54343,434343
1,232,100,4546,3456
1,122,45454,4546,3456
2,212,334,5555,4654

C:\Old_Data\perlp>perl t3.pl
1,122,45454
1,232,3534
2,212,334
```